# Form shows wrong date format while changing element in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I need the date format dd-mm-yyyy and I changed it everywhere. The date in the list of elements shows correctly. The database also has a requirement to enter the date in this format.
However, when I try to modify an existing element, the form shows a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd and I have to change the date to dd-mm-yyyy each time to make changes to the element, otherwise an error occurs. How can I make the date displayed in the format dd-mm-yyyy by default when editing an element?

`forms.py`

```
class CaseRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CaseRequest
        fields = ('name', 'datebirth')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'datebirth': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),                  
        }
```

`Models.py`

```
class CaseRequest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Put full name',max_length=255)
    datebirth = models.DateField('Put date in dd.mm.yy format')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('caserequest')
    @property
    def case_exists(self):
        return Case.objects.filter(name=self.name, datebirth=self.datebirth).exists()
```

`Views.py`

```
class UpdateCaseRequestView(UpdateView):
    model = CaseRequest
    form_class = CaseRequestForm
    template_name = 'add_caserequest.html'
```

`update_caserequest.py`

```
<div>
    <form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <button class="btn btn-secondary">Send</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

In `settings.py` I already added

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%d.%m.%Y"]
USE_L10N = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default widget for the `DateField` is `DateInput` not `TextInput`, that's for `CharField`.

You can override its format in the `widget` itself so:

```
from django.forms import DateInput

class CaseRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CaseRequest
        fields = ('name', 'datebirth')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'datebirth': DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}, format='%d-%m-%Y'),                    
        }
```

Now, the `date` input field in the form will use the `dd-mm-yyyy` format in the front-end.

Also provide `%d-%m-%y` in the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` since both are valid date formats so:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%d.%m.%Y", "%d-%m-%Y"]
USE_L10N = False
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. How many nerves you saved for me...